# @NgRx/Effects with Jasmine Marble testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, ngrx

I am creating a web app using Angular 4 and NgRx 4 and I am having some problems with unit testing.

I created the test below to see if I could get the return value of an effect:

```
it('should load orders and call load orders complete action', fakeAsync(() => {

    let responsePayload;
    const mockData = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

    const orderService = TestBed.get(OrderService);
    const testScheduler = new TestScheduler(null);
    orderService.getAllOrders.and.returnValue(hot('a|', { a: mockData }));

    actions = Observable.of(new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersAction(new Date()));

    const subscription = effects.loadAllOrders$.subscribe((result: orderActions.LoadAllOrdersCompleteAction) => {
      responsePayload = result.payload;
    });


    getTestScheduler().flush();
    tick();
    expect(responsePayload).toEqual(mockData);

    subscription.unsubscribe();

  }));
```

And this is the effect that I am testing:

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderEffect {

  @Effect()
  loadAllOrders$: Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType(orderActions.LOAD_ALL_ORDERS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$) // Get the latest state from the store and add as the second value of the array below
    .switchMap((input: any[]) => {
      const action: orderActions.LoadAllOrdersAction = input[0];
      const store: AppState = input[1];

      return Observable.timer(0, store.orders.pollingInterval) // Timer to create the polling effect.
        .switchMap(() => this.orderService.getAllOrders(action.payload)
          .map((orders: Array<any>) => new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersCompleteAction(orders))
          .catch(error => Observable.throw(new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersFailAction(error)))
        );
    });

  constructor(private actions: Actions, private orderService: OrderService, private store$: Store<AppState>) { }
}
```

However when I run this test I get the following error: `Expected undefined to equal [ Object({ id: 1 }), Object({ id: 2 }), Object({ id: 3 }) ].`

If I change this line of the test: `orderService.getAllOrders.and.returnValue(hot('a|', { a: mockData }));` to: `orderService.getAllOrders.and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockData));` then everything works, so I think that I am doing something wrong with the marble testing.

Please note that I am using the `jasmine-marbles` to import the `hot` and `cold` functions.

Below is the full code of the test that is working.

```
  it('should load orders and call load orders complete action', fakeAsync(() => {

    let responsePayload;
    const mockData = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

    const orderService = TestBed.get(OrderService);
    const testScheduler = new TestScheduler(null);
    orderService.getAllOrders.and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockData));

    actions = Observable.of(new orderActions.LoadAllOrdersAction(new Date()));

    const subscription = effects.loadAllOrders$.subscribe((result: orderActions.LoadAllOrdersCompleteAction) => {
      responsePayload = result.payload;
    });

    tick();
    expect(responsePayload).toEqual(mockData);

    subscription.unsubscribe();

  }));
```